# ReactiveCocoa - flattenMap block never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a problem using `flattenMap` method of `RACSignal` - the block never gets called. If I `subscribeNext` to the same signal, it works just fine, the problem is only with `flattenMap`.

Here's what works fine

```
[[self.aSignal combineLatestWith:self.otherSignal] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *tuple) {
    // gets called just fine
}];
```

And here's what doesn't work:

```
self.yetAnotherSignal = [[self.aSignal combineLatestWith:self.otherSignal] flattenMap:^RACStream *(RACTuple *tuple) {
    // never gets called
    return returnSignal;
}];
```

Am I missing something? Or do I misunderstand how `flattenMap` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're missing just one little bit: (at least in your snippet) no one is subscribing to your new signal!

You're constructing a new signal (`self.yetAnotherSignal`) from `self.aSignal` and `self.otherSignal` via `combineLatest` and `flattenMap`.

But that new signal, as well as any operators in the chain, do not actually do any work until it is subscribed in some form, the simplest form being via `subscribeNext` just as you did in your first snippet.

That is not just the case with `flattenMap`, its the same with any operation, e.g. `combineLatestWith` in your first example would not do anything if you would not subscribe to it. The same goes for `map`, `filter`, ... you name it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `combineLatestWith` won't send anything until both input signals send at least one value.